Request/response logging w/ Karate
I'm trying to suppress the request and the response being printed to the console, but keep them in the HTML report.
I've called karate.configure('report', false) in the global JS function, but that only keeps the request and response from showing up in the HTML report (the console still prints them each time), and changing the logger level in logback-test.xml to <logger name="com.intuit" level="INFO"/> successfully hides them in the console, but also keeps them from being printed in HTML report.
Is there a way to suppress them in the console, but still have them contained in the report?

Use this logback-test.xml file. Just comment out the STDOUT "root" appender-ref: This way you can view request response details in html report and hide these details in console.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
  
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>target/karate.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>    
   
    <logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>
   
    <root level="info">
       <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />-->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
  
</configuration>

